# Showing progress of a goal amount in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, currency

I have a rails for app that handles charity fundraising. A user can input a "goal" amount and I would like some advice on the best way to show the progress of the users fundraising.

I will ether generate the scaffold using the :decimal field to show the amount of perhaps use a money gem to handle the database side of the goal amount. But what would the be the BEST practice for displaying this progress. The pledges are accepted through paypals API is it as simple as linking that to a bootstrap3 progress bar?

Any experience or assistence would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly here's what I would recommend.

Use [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to log transaction data in your database.  You can do all sorts of post-transaction processing within an IPN solution and handle everything nice and neat, and in real-time.  Use this to maintain a database of transactions (payments, subscription profiles, disputes, refunds, etc.)

With a solid database structure of all your data, you can bind this to your progress bar(s) and anything you'd like to use to display the current status of the goal.

Really, the best way would be to also include a separate table for goals in your database.  You can send the goal ID in the CUSTOM parameter of PayPal payment requests, and that will come back in IPN so that you can log payments related to that goal ID.

Comment: Would you suggest using paypal IPN with a gem like money-rails? @AndrewAngell

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, but yeah, if you can find a code class that makes it easy on you I'd certainly recommend it.